# PHP Variables Link/Display

Tags: php

I'm passing variables from my Flash MP3 player to a PHP script to record what songs have played.  Now I want the PHP script to display one varable and include it in an Amazon link.

This is what I have but can't seem to get it to work.

```
<?php
$var1  = $_POST['var1']; //get the Artist Name and Title from Flash and store it in a PHP variable
$var2 = $_POST['var2']; //ignored
//This lines combines the two variables into one string. 
//To concatinate vars in PHP use a period or dot ".", much like Flash uses a plus sign "+". 

$add = $var1 . "+" . $var2 . "|";
//opens or creates (if it doesn't already exist) our text file (songsplayed.txt) 
//for writing (not reading) and places the pointer at the end.
$open = fopen('songsplayed.txt', 'a'); 
//writes to our specified file our string
$write = fwrite($open, $add); 

echo $var1;
echo

<a type="amzn" search=\"$var1\" category="music">
<img border="0" src="/buttons/buy-now-button-amazon.png" alt="Buy now @ Amazon"></a>
?>
```

Comment: Before you do anything further, you should read about cross-site scripting attacks. Printing unfiltered user input directly on the web page is unsafe: http://phpmaster.com/php-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-xss/

Comment: Is that your real php code? becase it stands now it's a flat-out syntax error. That final echo for the html is wrong: no quotes around the text

Comment: OT: You should spell words out in `alt`s versus using symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to echo HTML to the page without surrounding it with quotes. Try this instead:

```
<?php
$var1  = $_POST['var1']; //get the Artist Name and Title from Flash and store it in a PHP variable
$var2 = $_POST['var2']; //ignored
//This lines combines the two variables into one string. 
//To concatinate vars in PHP use a period or dot ".", much like Flash uses a plus sign "+". 

$add = $var1 . "+" . $var2 . "|";
//opens or creates (if it doesn't already exist) our text file (songsplayed.txt) 
//for writing (not reading) and places the pointer at the end.
$open = fopen('songsplayed.txt', 'a'); 
//writes to our specified file our string
$write = fwrite($open, $add); 

echo $var1;
?>
<a type="amzn" search="<?php echo $var1; ?>" category="music">
<img border="0" src="/buttons/buy-now-button-amazon.png" alt="Buy now @ Amazon"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
<?php
// minimal xss protection
$var1 = htmlentities($_POST['var1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$var2 = htmlentities($_POST['var2'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// one-line append
file_put_contents('songsplayed.txt', sprintf("%s+%s\r\n", $var1, $var2));
// proper echo'ing
echo $var1,
     '<a type="amzn" search="'. $var1 .'" category="music">',
     '<img border="0" src="/buttons/buy-now-button-amazon.png" alt="Buy now @ Amazon"></a>';
?>
```